# how to find the smallest number with exactly n distinct *prime* divisors

Tags: prime-factorization

I saw a question where it was just asking for the smallest number with n distinct divisors, but I'm looking for n distinct *prime* divisors. For example, the prime factorization of 8 is 2 * 2 * 2, so it has one distinct prime divisor. Another example is 12 (2 * 2 * 3), which has 2 distinct prime divisors. Is there a formula to do this (preferably one that can easily be implemented into python)? If n = 24, the smallest number with 24 distinct prime divisors is 23768741896345550770650537601358310.

Comment: Let $\{p_j\}_j$ be the enumeration of the primes from smallest on up.  The smallest number with exactly $n$ prime divisors is $\prod_{j=1}^{n} p_j$, no?

Comment: ... also known as primorial

Comment: In plain terms: the product of the first $n$ primes (starting from $2$).

Comment: There are fast, compact prime sieves in Python here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/4014959 both with & without Numpy. There are various prime generators here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2211990/4014959 They're slower than sieves, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smallest number with $n$ distinct prime factors, and the $n$-th number in the list, is the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) $p_n\#$ of the $n$-th prime $p_n$, like $p_4\#  = 7\#=2\cdot3\cdot 5\cdot 7$.  See also [OEIS A002110](https://oeis.org/A002110).

$$\begin{align}
2 &= 2 \\
6 &= 2\cdot3 \\
30 &= 2\cdot3\cdot 5 \\
210 &= 2\cdot3\cdot 5\cdot 7 \\
&\ \vdots
\end{align}$$

There are  [formulas that generate primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes), but none is well suited for computation.

For any practical purposes, first generate a list of primes, for example by a sieve algorithm like [Eratosthenes'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Because you will always only encounter small primes of just a few decimals, you can also generate list of primes by checking divisors up to $\sqrt n$, as the overhead should be neglectable compared to heave number-theoretic machinery like pseudo-primality test together with primality-proofs and -certificates.

Comment: I think you might have made a mistake. 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 is 210, which is the 4th number in the sequence. Other than that, I think this is what I was looking for!

Comment: @GoldLemur82303 oops, fixed it.